# perl template toolkit TRY not working

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I have to test for the presence of file and then load. but it seems variable substitution inside () is not working:

```
>     [% TRY %]
>        [% USE File("myfile.$userid") %]
>        [% INCLUDE "myfile.$userid" %]
>     [% CATCH File %]
>        [% INCLUDE "myfile.general" %]
>     [% END %]
```

can anyone advice a better way? or point to mistake?

ty.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue.
it needed full absolute path to the file.

so following works:

```
[% USE File("/absolute_path/myfile.$userid") %]
```